# Update all crate `branch` in Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Using `$ cargo`, is there a way to update the `branch` from, say, `branch = v1.0.1` to `branch = v1.0.2` for many dependencies in a workspace?

Comment: Do you mean in your a command which updates your `Cargo.toml` file with the latest version number? There isn't a way to do that, but depending on how you [specify your dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) Cargo can grab a newer version after `cargo update`.

Comment: This was to update the `branch` of each one. Might just be something for vim...

Comment: Oh, by "branch" do you mean specifically for git repos?

Comment: Yep, like `pallet-contracts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }`

Comment: got it, I read `branch` as the name of a crate at first. I'm not sure if Cargo can handle those because they don't have semver requirements like crates.io does, but hopefully somebody else has an idea/workaround